# Why isn't my synchronized method working?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

Simply put, i'm trying to see the difference when using sychronized keyword over just running a function over threads without locks at all.

In this code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class mainClass {
static int count=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Runnable r =new Runnable() {

        public synchronized void run() {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    };
    IntStream.range(0, 10000)
            .forEach(i -> executor.submit(r::run));

    executor.shutdown();

    System.out.println(count);  // 10000

}
}
```

It doesn't work as i predicated it to work, it returns 10000 in like 40% of the runs. Why is that? Where is the problem?
I thought that the function run is being run by only 1 Thread at a time, so there shouldn't be problem, but clearly i'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExecutorService#shutdown` does not wait for tasks to complete. You should use `awaitTermination` for that.

See the [documentation for ExecutorService#shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()).

```
IntStream.range(0, 10000)
        .forEach(i -> executor.submit(r::run));

executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTE); // <!-- HERE
```

Comment: and remove the shutdown :)

Comment: @VeselinDavidov You still need the shutdown. `awaitTermination` "Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request"

Comment: You don't remove the shutdown. Calling `awaitTermination` after calling `shutdown` is exactly the way to go about it.

Comment: @ptomli in this simple use case you don't exactly *need* the `shutdown` - the `awaitTermination` will simply wait a minute and then all Tasks are finished anyways in all probability ;) Just to be 100% precise. Using shutdown is definitely the correct way though.

Comment: @Ben I just had to test that `awaitTermination` actually blocked in the absence of a prior invocation of `shutdown`. It seems it does, the docs didn't strike me as unambiguous either way. Good to know though.

Comment: Well, after 15 minutes of fighting with the code (unhandeled exception first, and then i had some intelij related problem) I solved it.

Thank you very much!